# Code that changes frequently

Tags: java, terminology

Is there a specific word that can be used to refer "Code that changes frequently".

For eg. A "Boilerplate code" refers to sections of code that is repeated often in different classes with little changes.

Comment: "volatile"? PS: Not to be confused with the `volatile` keyword.

Comment: I don't think there's a standard term, I personally use "unstable".

Comment: Do you mean polymorphism where the same method call to different objects return a different result depending on the implementation? (ref: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming).

Comment: @Peter Unstable sounds quite close, but still not the one which I need.  Volatile more signifies the code that may be lost, so it is not what I need.  Polymorphism is definitely not what I need.

Comment: My first thought for your new term would be 'poorly designed'.  What is an E.G. for 'Code that changes frequently'?

Comment: Unstable is already taken - it means "code compiles, but unit test(s) are failing". I like "volatile".

Comment: @AndrewThompson A particular business logic might need to be adapted many times depending on how the business changes over time.  So, this is some code which you will not write only once but may have to make modifications to adapt changes to the business.

Comment: @Bohemian Thanks for pointing out that unstable is taken.  Well volatile is also taken :-) Volatile is a term generally used with data - Its the opposite of persistent data.  So using this will cause ambiguity.

Comment: The phrase "code churn" is sometimes used to refer to the situation where code is frequently (perhaps too frequently) changing.